# `throw new Error('Failed to load static props')` when setting `fallback: true` in `getStaticPaths` in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Refer to discussion [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11862). I faced similar error. Everything worked fine when `fallback` is set to `false`. However, when fallback is set to true, next js throws error

```
 throw new Error('Failed to load static props')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After lot of searching and trial and error, I found out that the error was because of the exceptions throws inside `getStaticProps`.

To solve this issue all I did is to use try-catch block.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  let data = null;
  try {
    data = await getData(params.slug);
  } catch (err) { };

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
```

And when rendering your can use

```
if(props.data) return (<your-jsx-here></your-jsx-here>)
else return <div>Any message if you want</div>
```

Comment: This helped solve the errors, but I am still unable to display the data from an API. It seems, that it is getting stuck on the `Loading...` condition and unable to load the data when it has fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my answer here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11862:

> Your getStaticProps should return a boolean like `notFound: true`, and your page can render a 404 page or the `next/error` page. This would allow the page to eventually become real (if the missing slug is created in backend).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this issue using `notFound: true` inside `getStaticProps`.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { id } }) {

  const res = await fetch(`{{api}}/items?id=${id}`);
  const item = await res.json();

  const notFound = item[0] ? false : true;

  return {
    props: {
      item: item[0]
    },
    revalidate: 10,
    notFound
  };
}
```