# Next's getStaticProps is not returning props in production

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js

I am trying to use Next js's getStaticProps to fetch data from an API and display it. When I test my app locally, the website shows the data from the API, but when I push it to production (AWS Amplify), I am getting not rendering of the data. I am not sure why this is the case.

When my code runs in the browser, it is stuck on the `Loading...` text and the data never appears.

Here is a link to the [live production site](https://main.d39cqr3ga5brto.amplifyapp.com/park/care)

Here is my code:

```js
export default function Park({parkInfo}) {

  // only render the data from the API once it has loaded
  if (parkInfo) {
    const {
      name,
      description
    } = parkInfo

    return (
      <>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h1>{description}</h1>
      </>
    )
  // while the data is loading, show a loading text
  } else {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: true,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
  //  Set the base URL for the API
  const URL = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/'

  // Set data to null to handle errors
  let parkInfo = null

  const reqBody = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': '*',
    },
  }

  // Call API Data for /PARK
  try {
    const parkData = await fetch(
      `${URL}parks?parkCode=${params?.parkCode}&limit=465&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
      reqBody
    )

    parkInfo = await parkData.json()
    parkInfo = parkInfo?.data[0]

    // only send the necessary data to the front end
    parkInfo = {
      name: parkInfo?.name,
      description: parkInfo?.description,
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  return {
    props: {
      parkInfo,
    },
    revalidate: 86400, // revalidate once per day
  }
}
```

I am not getting an errors in the console because I've caught them with the conditional statement in the return above in the jsx.

I've also used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946219/throw-new-errorfailed-to-load-static-props-when-setting-fallback-true-i), but I am still unable to return live data in the production site.

Comment: Can I have access to your solution repo?

Comment: @RyanLe Hi Ryan, yes. You can access that here: https://github.com/tyler-morales/visit-national-parks

Specifically, this file is under /pages/park/[parkCode].js

Comment: Do you see any server-side errors occurring in the Amplify logs? I'm assuming the `fetch` request is failing for some reason and `parkInfo` is being returned as `null` from `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves Where can I access the Amplify logs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amplify, but maybe these docs have the answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-logs.html.

Comment: @juliomalves After taking a look at the logs, I am only seeing 200 requests which sounds good. However, after taking a broader look, I came across an issue where the API key seems to be incorrect. Here is that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226602/how-to-make-production-environmental-variables-with-aws-amplify-and-next-js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getServerSideProps` instead of `getStaticProps`.
`getStaticProps` is for static site generation. Its return value is fixed at build time.
See this documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props

Comment: Nothing on that page needs server side generation. It can all be made at build time. Why would I want to use SSR?

Comment: @TylerMorales You mentioned "live data", so I thought you want to render the page dynamically. I just missed "revalidate" line.

Comment: getStaticProps is also for Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR), when combined with getStaticPaths