# How to make production environmental variables with AWS Amplify and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, aws-amplify

I have an API key that I need to access an API endpoint. In my Next.js app, I store this key under `.env.local` like so:

```
API_KEY=qwerty123
```

And I access it in my `getStaticProps` function with the process.env:

```js
 const parkData = await fetch(
      `${URL}parks?parkCode=${params?.parkCode}&limit=465&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
      reqBody
    )
```

When I try to run this in production I am getting an error that the API key is invalid. I know that the API is correct because when I run the project locally, the API data loads.

```
    "code": "API_KEY_INVALID",
    "message": "Your API key is not valid. Please get a new one at https://www.nps.gov/subjects/developer/get-started.htm"
```

My question is do I need to change how I call the API key in my `getStaticProps` function for the production build?

Note: I've made sure to included the env in the Amplify console.

[image]

Comment: The way you're using it should work. Are you sure the API key has the same value as your local one?

Comment: I've double checked that the key is the same in my .env.locla and environment keys in the Amplify console. Still getting the same error

Comment: Is the URL you're making the request against also the same in your local and prod envs?

Comment: Yes. I call the api like this: 
const URL = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/';

const parkData = await fetch(
      `${URL}parks?parkCode=${params?.parkCode}&limit=465&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    )

Answer (score 5):

## Environment variables are not carried through to Lambda functions

For some reason, I'm not sure why myself, you still have to add the env's in your next.config.js file.

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    MY_ENV_VAR: process.env.MY_ENV_VAR
  }
};
```

[Amplify troubleshooting docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#ssr-environment-variable-support)