# Contentful with AWS Amplify and Next.js: TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, contentful

I have a Next.js app hosted on AWS Amplify. I have a static page with a named export `getStaticProps` where I use contentful, like this:

```js
const client = contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_KEY,
})
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken
at Module.createClient (/var/task/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:10095:11)
```

even though I added the `CONTENTFUL_SPACE` and `CONTENTFUL_API_KEY` environment variables in the AWS Amplify dashboard.

I don't get this issue when using Vercel. Does anyone know why I am getting this error on AWS Amplify even though I added the environment variables in the Amplify dashboard?

Comment: Hey, maybe this documentation page(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-environment-variables.html) can be helpful? I also found a solution that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226602/how-to-make-production-environmental-variables-with-aws-amplify-and-next-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this error:

In my `next.config.js`, I added:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    CONTENTFUL_SPACE: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE,
    CONTENTFUL_API_KEY: process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_KEY,

  }
}
```

The reason this was necessary and the reason the environment variables weren’t accessible in `getStaticProps` on AWS Amplify is because **Environment variables are not carried through to Lambda functions** which is where `getStaticProps` runs.